# Is this an effective method to calculate elapsed time for a page to process?

Tags: php

I am trying to count how long it takes for a page to complete loading.

What I thought of was something simple like:

```
$start = microtime();

do_this_function();

do_that_function();

$end = microtime();

$elapsed = $end - $start;
```

I don't know if this is effective or not, as sometimes I am getting negative values. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to read the definition of `microtime`

> `microtime ($get_as_float = null)`
>
> When called without the optional argument, this function returns the
>   string "msec sec" where sec is the current time measured in the number
>   of seconds since the Unix Epoch (0:00:00 January 1, 1970 GMT), and
>   msec is the microseconds part.

So just call `microtime` with the first param set to true

```
$start = microtime(true);

do_this_function();

do_that_function();

$end = microtime(true);

$elapsed = $end - $start;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in the beginning of the page

```
<?php
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$time = $time[1] + $time[0];
$start = $time;
?>
```

And this at the end:

```
<?php
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$time = $time[1] + $time[0];
$finish = $time;
$total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);
echo 'Page generated in '.$total_time.' seconds.';
?>
```

I think this will do what you need.